# Are quotes necessary in bash when declaring local variables based on the command line argument variable expansion?

Tags: bash, variables, syntax, command-line-arguments, quoting

Are the quotes in the below example necessary or superfluous. And why?

```
#!/bin/bash

arg1="$1"
arg2="$2"
```

How do you explain the fact when `$1` is `123 echo abc`, the first assignment is not interpreted as:

```
arg1=123 echo abc
```

which is a normal command (`echo`) call with argument `abc` and an environment variable (`arg`) passed to the execution.

Comment: Even if the syntax *didn't* specify that assignments don't go through string-splitting, that doesn't mean you can get from `arg=$1` to `arg=123 echo abc` *with the arg=123 interpreted as a transient environment variable assignment*. Parsing for syntax (and such environment variables' assignments are indeed syntax) happens **before** variable expansion; this is also why you can't set `var='if'` and then run `$var foo; then bar; fi`, because keywords (like assignments!) are only recognized prior to the point when parameter expansion takes place.

Comment: Related post on U&L Stack Exchange: [Are quotes needed for local variable assignment?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97569/201820).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [section 2.9.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_2_9_1) of the POSIX shell syntax specification:

> Each variable assignment shall be expanded for **tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal** prior to assigning the value.

String-splitting and globbing (the steps which double quotes suppress) are not in this list.

Thus, the quotes are superfluous -- not just for assignments where the right-and side refers to a positional parameter, but for *all* assignments barring those where (1) the behavior of single-quoted, not double-quoted, strings are desired; or (2) whitespace or other content in the value would be otherwise parsed as syntactic rather than literal.

---

<sub>(Note that the decision on how to parse a command -- thus, whether it is an assignment, a simple command, a compound command, or something else -- takes place *before* parameter expansions; thus, `var=$1` is determined to be an assignment before the value of `$1` is ever considered! Were this untrue, such that data could silently become syntax, it would be far more difficult -- if not impossible -- to write secure code handling untrusted data in bash).</sub>

Comment: While superfluous in this context, quoting is so important in all others that I feel assignments to should be quoted to reinforce the habit.

Comment: As a matter of best practice, I agree.

Comment: How should I properly read this? `$1` is expanded (prior to assignment), this generates white spaces and then bash should work as I describe: execute `echo`. Is there a difference between how `$1` and a normal variable `$var` are processed? Can we also say that quotes are always superfluous for all single-variable-expansion assignments?

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay, yes, quotes are superfluous for assignments *in general*, except where there would be syntactic whitespace causing them to otherwise be parsed as an entirely different kind of command. They're just as superfluous for `arg3=${foo}${bar}`, for example.

Comment: Yours is better than any of the answers on the duplicate, could you please repost it there (and perhaps delete it from here)?

Comment: @tripleee, ...done; can't delete from here due to accepted status, but flagged this copy community-wiki.